# Displaying html web page through php?

Tags: php, html, web

I'm just starting with **PHP** and tried to design a simple code where I define some multidimensional arrays of integers randomly generated and display them to a web page.

However, when I try to acess to the `.php` served by **Apache**, web browser is not displaying the web page. What's that missing in my code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Novatos del PHP
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>



    <?php

        $m1 = array (   array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100))
                    );

        $m2 = array (   array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100)), 
                        array (rand(0,100), rand(0,100), rand(0,100))
                    );

        printMatrix($m1);


        function printMatrix($matrix){
            echo "<table width=\"200\" border=\"1\">";

            foreach($matrix as $row =$rValue){
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($rValue as $col =$cValue){
                    echo "<td>".$cValue."</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }

    ?>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What web server are you running?

Comment: You should be able to see those errors if you turn error reporting on, or in your Apache logs. Also you forgot the DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($matrix as $row =$rValue)
```

should be (on both rows)

```
foreach($matrix as $row => $rValue)
```

Do you just get a white page? Maybe you should make sure error_reporting is on.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: However, doing that I'm overwriting the columns values, not iterating over the matrix. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Of course you need to use different variables in each foreach statement. I was just trying to point out that you need to use the "arrow" (=>) in both instances.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a server which can actually serve the PHP pages? E.g. Apache?
If not, check out this page:
* http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html cross platform;

Comment: Yes, I'm under Apache